# vsftpd, virtual users and permissions. Avoid using chmod 777?

Tags: centos, permissions, ftp, centos6.4

I am running `vsftpd` with Virtual Users (managed through a MySQL db). Each users home/default directory is owned by `vsftpd:vsftpd`.

I need to give a user read/write permissions to some website files, owned by `apache:apache` so they can make some changes. I did a bind mount for the web directory to a directory in the ftp user's home/default directory. When logging in, the user is not able to write to the web folder, unless I set files to 777.

Is it possible to set this up with making the directory and it's files 777? The web directory needs to be `apache:apache` in order for apache to work with it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to work with chmod 777 if the files are static. If the files get created dynamically or you don't want to give everybody access you can use ACLs. For that you need to activate ACLs if not active yet (mount option). Then you could set permissions like this:

```
setfacl -R -m user:apache:rwx -m default:user:apache:rwx /path/to/website/dir
setfacl -R -m user:ftp:rwx -m default:user:ftp:rwx /path/to/website/dir
```

These commands set write permissions recursively for the users ftp and apache so that they are inherited for new files.